# Why need relation-table from entity to same entity

Tags: mysql, hibernate, relation

I got a roo-script-line like this:

field set --class Member --fieldName invitedby --type Member --cardinality ONE_TO_MANY

Hibernate require a table named member_invitedby with column member and invitedby:

```
PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: megaadmin] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: megaadmin] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:286)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: member_invitedby
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1272)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:506)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
        ... 28 more
```

If i manualy create a table member_invitedby with columns member and invitedby this exception goes away.

I dont know why hibernate need a n-m table because of one Member can only be invited by one Member, its a 1-n!

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The default way of mapping a OneToMany unidirectional association is to use a join table. This avoid polluting the child (many) side with a join column, since it's not supposed to know its parent (the one side).

If you want a foreign key at the many side, referencing the one side, then you need to say it explicitely using an @JoinColumn annotation on the OneToMany association declaration. How to do that with Roo, I don't know.

Comment: along my personal concept: its rarely true that a self-1-n is not part of the being of the entity s.o. polluting the child s.o. its an antipattern. Hey, can you please explain by concrete example when a child gets polluting?

Comment: Let's say you have a User and an Address. A user has multiple addresses. But Offices also have addresses. And Companies also have addresses. And Contacts also have addresses. Addresses don't need to know if they're for a user, an office, a company or a contact. So the association is a unidirectional one-to-many association in every case. You don't want 4 foreign keys in the address table to do that. And if you add a Provider to the set of entities which have an address, you don't want to add yet another nullable foreign key in the address table. Join tables are a better choice in this case.

Comment: Continued: That's at least what the JPA spec thinks, so they decided to make it the default in case of unidirectional one-to-many associations. But they let you the choice to do otherwise by aing a JoinColumn annotation to the association if you prefer mapping the association using a joi column. And if the association is bidirectional, the default is to use a join column.

Comment: Your example shows the need of 1-n relation-talbes between *different* entitys very well. What about a self-1-n relation from Address to Address like "address.old_address_id(nullable) -> address.id" (guess two persons get married and abite together in a new address)?

Comment: JPA dosn't care about the target of an association. The default is the same for all one-to-many unidirectional associations. Since it's easy to override the default, it makes the spec easier to understand, while still flexible.

Comment: I got a relation from Member.organization_id -> Organization.id. This relation dont need a relation table. There must be an difference be between self-1-n and 1-n.